# How to parse JSON Data in Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

I'm new to corona, and I am having issues while parsing JSON data from server in corona sdk.
Data is coming from the server in the response properly and is getting printed.
While parsing, I don't get data in my variable. It either shows none of the data or nil value.

Here is my json data structure:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "data":{
    "marks":[
    {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Sharma",
    "country_id":"20",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
   }
},
   {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Yadav",
    "country_id":"21",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
    {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Pankaj",
    "last_name":"Shukla",
    "country_id":"22",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
    {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Abhishek",
    "last_name":"Tiwari",
    "country_id":"25",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
    {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Kashif",
    "last_name":"Khan",
    "country_id":"20",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Ankit",
    "last_name":"Sharma",
    "country_id":"19",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Rahul",
    "last_name":"Vishwakarma",
    "country_id":"27",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Tiwari",
    "country_id":"30",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Sharma",
    "country_id":"78",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Sharma",
    "country_id":"23",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

How can i copy the json data in a variable and display it in corona
and here is my json data code

```
  function networkListener(event)
       if(event.isError) then 
         native.setActivityIndicator(false)
         print("Network Error")
        local ErrText=display.newText(....)
       else 
         native.setActivityIndicator(false)
         print("Response".. event.response)
         data=json.decode(event.response)
         for i=1,#data do
         local fname=data.score[i].scores.first_name
         print(fname)
     end
   end
   end
```

Comment: Should i use the following code to print my data                   local t = json.decode( txt ) for i=1 #t do
print(t["first_name"])
print(t["last_name"])
print(t["Country_id"])
print(t["Physics"])
print(t["Chemistry"])
print(t["Mathematics"])

Comment: I have checked the link you have provided and implemented but it is not working. It is working on the simple json format data, but not in the above format

Comment: this question is not a duplicate, dk3611, did you answer this?